# How to debug a crash before main?

Tags: c, gdb

My program links statically to many libraries and crashes before getting to `main` in GDB. How do I diagnose what the problem is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a good bet that `LD_DEBUG` can help you here. Try this: `LD_DEBUG=all ./a.out`. This will allow you to easily identify the library which is being loaded when your program crashes.

(Edit: if it wasn't clear, `a.out` is meant to refer to a generic binary file -- in this case, replace it with the name of your executable).

Edit 2:

To clarify, `LD_DEBUG` is an environment variable which is examined by the dynamic linker when a program begins execution. If `LD_DEBUG` is set to some value, the dynamic linker will output a lot of information about the dynamic libraries being loaded during program execution, symbol binding, and so on.

For starters, execute the following on your machine:

```
LD_DEBUG=help ls
```

You will see the valid options for `LD_DEBUG` on your system listed. The most verbose setting is `all`, which will display all available information.

Now, to use this is as simple as the `ls` example, only replace `ls` with the name of your program. There is no need for gdb in order to use LD_DEBUG, as it is functionality provided solely by the dynamic linker, and not by gdb.

Comment: how exactly do I add this? that doesnt look like a gdb function

Comment: @denniston.t, `LD_DEBUG` is for debugging shared libraries, but here program is linked statically. It will not help if the bug is in static library.

Comment: @ks1322: Whoops, I missed that part of the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: could you please explain anyways, it may well be that the statically linked libraries themselves link other libraries dynamically

Comment: @chacham15: I've updated my answer with more details: it isn't a gdb command, but an environment variable you specify upon executing your program.

Answer (score 4):

It may crash because some component throws an exception and nobody catches it since `main()` hasn't been entered yet. Set a breakpoint on throwing an exception:

```
catch throw
run
```

(If `catch throw` doen't work the first time you start it, run it once to let it load the dynamic libraries and then do `catch throw` and run again).

Comment: its c, not c++. gdb returns: "Function "__cxa_throw" not defined."

Answer (score 4):

This post has the answer, you have to set a breakpoint before main in the crt0 startup code:
[Using GDB without debugging symbols on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321985/using-gdb-without-debugging-symbols-on-x86)

Comment: Function "__libc_start_main" not defined.

Comment: your program will have something similar.  you can find out what your actual execution entry point is by running readelf -h on your executable.  You can set a breakpoint on the Entry point address it shows you.

Comment: the problem with this is once it stopped, i have no way to 'iterate through the libraries'.

Answer (score 4):

**`starti`**

`starti` breaks at the very first instruction executed, see also: [Stopping at the first machine code instruction in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb/48588442#48588442)

An alternative if your GDB is not new enough:

```
break _start
```

if you know the that the name of the entry point method is `_start`, or:

```
info files
```

search for `Entry point`:

```
 Entry point: 0x400440
```

and run:

```
 break *0x400440
```

TODO: find out how to compile `crt*` objects with debug symbols and step into them: [How to compile my own glibc C standard library from source and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412684/how-to-compile-my-own-glibc-c-standard-library-from-source-and-use-it/52454710#52454710)

Answer (score 3):

Start taking the libraries out one by one until it stops crashing.
Then examine the culprit.

Comment: Really?  That's not particularly realistic.  Some programs are large and removing a library means lots of references that will now no longer link.

Comment: @Joe yeah, sometimes you have to actually, you know, do difficult things.  You have a better suggestion?

Comment: Or use `LD_DEBUG` as a shortcut to help accomplish the same thing (see my answer).

Comment: It was annoying and took a reeeealy long time, but this is what i did.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't run into this in C but if you link to a c++ library static initialization can crash.  You can create it easily by having an assert in a constructor of a static scope variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, link your program dynamically instead of statically and follow @denniston.t [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808769/how-to-debug-a-crash-before-main/7809744#7809744). Maybe debug trace from dynamic linker will help to fix this problem.