# How to compile my own glibc C standard library from source and use it?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I am trying to compile my own glibc. I have a directory `glibc`, which contain the `glibc` source code I downloaded from the internet. From that directory I typed `mkdir ../build-glibc`. Now from the `build-glibc` directory I typed `../glibc/configure`, which performed the configuration. Now I'm not sure how to call `make`. I can't call it from `glibc` directory since it doesn't have the configuration set, neither I can call it from `build-glibc`, since makefile is not in that directory. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: did you read http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Installation ?

Comment: Yes I read it, it just says call make, but my question is from where should I call make and how? I can't call it from build directory and neither from the glibc directory because configure was not called from there.

Comment: Run `make` from the directory that contains the make file.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, It says the following. The GNU C library has not been configured.
Run `configure' to configure it before building.
Try `configure --help' for more details.
make: Failed to remake makefile `sysdeps/../config.make'. And if I try to call ./configure from the same directory it says use a separate build directory.

Comment: Then apparently `configure` failed. Did it produce an error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Makefile` is going to exist in your `build-glibc` directory if the `configure` script finishes successfully.

If everything *seems* to have gone smoothly during `configure` and still no `Makefile`, then you probably missed an idiosyncrasy:

While doing a `configure` for glibc, it is expected that you normally provide an alternative `--prefix`, because installing to the default location (`/usr/local`) can potentially cripple the system. If you don't provide one, then you need to switch on `--disable-sanity-checks`.

If this is not the case either, look for a `config.log` file, and read its contents.

Answer (score 40):

### Setup 1: glibc without dedicated GCC

This setup might work and is quick as it does not recompile the whole GCC toolchain, just glibc.

The only problem I have with this setup is that I haven't found a nice way to use runtime objects such as `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` provided by our glibc, and I'm using the host ones for now. This is mentioned at: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location Those objects do early setup that glibc relies on, so I wouldn't be surprised if things crashed in wonderful and awesomely subtle ways. See attempts at solving this below.

Build glibc and install locally:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.32
mkdir build
cd build
export glibc_install="$(pwd)/install"
../configure --prefix "$glibc_install"
make -j `nproc`
make install -j `nproc`
```

#### Setup 1: verify the build

test_glibc.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <threads.h>

atomic_int acnt;
int cnt;

int f(void* thr_data) {
    for(int n = 0; n < 1000; ++n) {
        ++cnt;
        ++acnt;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* Basic library version check. */
    printf("gnu_get_libc_version() = %s\n", gnu_get_libc_version());

    /* Exercise thrd_create from -pthread,
     * which is not present in glibc 2.27 in Ubuntu 18.04.
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810/how-do-i-start-threads-in-plain-c/52453291#52453291 */
    thrd_t thr[10];
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_create(&thr[n], f, NULL);
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        thrd_join(thr[n], NULL);
    printf("The atomic counter is %u\n", acnt);
    printf("The non-atomic counter is %u\n", cnt);
}
```

Compile and run with `test_glibc.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
gcc \
  -L "${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -I "${glibc_install}/include" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${glibc_install}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -std=c11 \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  -v \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd ./test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

Command adapted from https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location

The program outputs the expected:

```
gnu_get_libc_version() = 2.32
The atomic counter is 10000
The non-atomic counter is 8674
```

`ldd` output confirms that the `ldd` and libraries that we've just built are actually being used as expected:

```
+ ldd test_glibc.out
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe4bfd3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc12ed92000)
        libc.so.6 => /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc12e9dc000)
        /home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc12f1b3000)
```

The `gcc` compilation debug output shows that my host runtime objects were used, which is bad as mentioned previously, but I don't know how to work around it, e.g. it contains:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
```

#### Setup 1: modify glibc

Now let's modify glibc with:

```
diff --git a/nptl/thrd_create.c b/nptl/thrd_create.c
index 113ba0d93e..b00f088abb 100644
--- a/nptl/thrd_create.c
+++ b/nptl/thrd_create.c
@@ -16,11 +16,14 @@
    License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
    <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

+#include <stdio.h>
+
 #include "thrd_priv.h"

 int
 thrd_create (thrd_t *thr, thrd_start_t func, void *arg)
 {
+  puts("hacked");
   _Static_assert (sizeof (thr) == sizeof (pthread_t),
                   "sizeof (thr) != sizeof (pthread_t)");
```

Then recompile and re-install glibc, and recompile and re-run our program:

```
cd glibc/build
make -j `nproc`
make -j `nproc` install
./test_glibc.sh
```

and we see `hacked` printed a few times as expected.

This further confirms that we actually used the glibc that we compiled and not the host one.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

#### Setup 1: attempts at using the correct `crt*` objects

https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds?action=recall&rev=21#Compile_against_glibc_in_an_installed_location suggests adding `--sysroot` to the `gcc` command but:

- it does not really change the objects to ours according to logs
- and it makes compilation fail with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libgcc_s.so.1` presumably because the `sysroot` gets used for this GCC provided object, which we don't have at that sysroot because we only built glibc

At https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634184/895245 ZeZNiQ provides a workaround that is likely correct, by passing:

```
-nostartfiles
```

followed by all the objects. You just need to extract the correct objects from the full command with `-nostartfiles` and pass them manually.

For example, on my amd64 machine, the objects used were different from his 32-bit command, so this is a bit fiddly.

Bibliography:

- [How do I change GCC's default search directory for crti.o?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904902/how-do-i-change-gccs-default-search-directory-for-crti-o)
- https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2015-02/msg00016.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2001-11/msg00029.html

### Setup 2: crosstool-NG pristine setup

This is an alternative to setup 1, and it is the most correct setup I've achieved far: everything is correct as far as I can observe, including the C runtime objects such as `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o`.

In this setup, we will compile a full dedicated GCC toolchain that uses the glibc that we want.

The only downside to this method is that the build will take longer. But I wouldn't risk a production setup with anything less.

[crosstool-NG](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng) is a set of scripts that downloads and compiles everything from source for us, including GCC, glibc and binutils.

Yes the GCC build system is so bad that we need a separate project for that.

This setup is only not perfect because [crosstool-NG does not support building the executables without extra `-Wl` flags](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1030), which feels weird since we've built GCC itself. But everything seems to work, so this is only an inconvenience.

Get crosstool-NG, configure and build it:

```
git clone https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng
cd crosstool-ng
git checkout a6580b8e8b55345a5a342b5bd96e42c83e640ac5
export CT_PREFIX="$(pwd)/.build/install"
export PATH="/usr/lib/ccache:${PATH}"
./bootstrap
./configure --enable-local
make -j `nproc`
./ct-ng x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
./ct-ng menuconfig
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng build CT_JOBS=`nproc`
```

The build takes about thirty minutes to two hours.

The only mandatory configuration option that I can see, is making it match your host kernel version to use the correct kernel headers. Find your host kernel version with:

```
uname -a
```

which shows me:

```
4.15.0-34-generic
```

so in `menuconfig` I do:

- `Operating System`

  - `Version of linux`

so I select:

```
4.14.71
```

which is the first equal or older version. It has to be older since the kernel is backwards compatible.

#### Setup 2: optional configurations

The `.config` that we generated with `./ct-ng x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` has:

```
CT_GLIBC_V_2_27=y
```

To change that, in `menuconfig` do:

- `C-library`
- `Version of glibc`

save the `.config`, and continue with the build.

Or, if you want to use your own glibc source, e.g. to use glibc from the latest git, proceed [like this](https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1024):

- `Paths and misc options`

  - `Try features marked as EXPERIMENTAL`: set to true
- `C-library`

  - `Source of glibc`

    - `Custom location`: say yes
    - `Custom location`

      - `Custom source location`: point to a directory containing your glibc source

where glibc was cloned as:

```
git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout glibc-2.28
```

#### Setup 2: test it out

Once you have built he toolchain that you want, test it out with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
install_dir="${CT_PREFIX}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
PATH="${PATH}:${install_dir}/bin" \
  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${install_dir}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${install_dir}/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib" \
  -v \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
ldd test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

Everything seems to work as in Setup 1, except that now the correct runtime objects were used:

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS=/home/ciro/crosstool-ng/.build/install/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/../x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o
```

#### Setup 2: failed efficient glibc recompilation attempt

It does not seem possible with crosstool-NG, as explained below.

If you just re-build;

```
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng build CT_JOBS=`nproc`
```

then your changes to the custom glibc source location are taken into account, but it builds everything from scratch, making it unusable for iterative development.

If we do:

```
./ct-ng list-steps
```

it gives a nice overview of the build steps:

```
Available build steps, in order:
  - companion_tools_for_build
  - companion_libs_for_build
  - binutils_for_build
  - companion_tools_for_host
  - companion_libs_for_host
  - binutils_for_host
  - cc_core_pass_1
  - kernel_headers
  - libc_start_files
  - cc_core_pass_2
  - libc
  - cc_for_build
  - cc_for_host
  - libc_post_cc
  - companion_libs_for_target
  - binutils_for_target
  - debug
  - test_suite
  - finish
Use "<step>" as action to execute only that step.
Use "+<step>" as action to execute up to that step.
Use "<step>+" as action to execute from that step onward.
```

therefore, we see that there are glibc steps intertwined with several GCC steps, most notably `libc_start_files` comes before `cc_core_pass_2`, which is likely the most expensive step together with `cc_core_pass_1`.

In order to build just one step, you must first set the "Save intermediate steps" in `.config` option for the intial build:

- `Paths and misc options`

  - `Debug crosstool-NG`

    - `Save intermediate steps`

and then you can try:

```
env -u LD_LIBRARY_PATH time ./ct-ng libc+ -j`nproc`
```

but unfortunately, the `+` required as mentioned at: https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng/issues/1033#issuecomment-424877536

> Note however that restarting at an intermediate step resets the installation directory to the state it had during that step. I.e., you will have a rebuilt libc - but no final compiler built with this libc (and hence, no compiler libraries like libstdc++ either).

and basically still makes the rebuild too slow to be feasible for development, and I don't see how to overcome this without patching crosstool-NG.

Furthermore, starting from the `libc` step didn't seem to copy over the source again from `Custom source location`, further making this method unusable.

### Bonus: stdlibc++

A bonus if you're also interested in the C++ standard library: [How to edit and re-build the GCC libstdc++ C++ standard library source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872229/how-to-edit-and-re-build-the-gcc-libstdc-c-standard-library-source/51946224#51946224)

Comment: is this the longest answer on SO?

Comment: @niCkcAMel these are likely my longest (work intensive) answers so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/how-to-run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/32483545#32483545 | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor/30648229#30648229

Comment: Hi @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功  Is there glibc included in gcc-9.3 https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/?

Comment: @calvin I haven't heart about such changes, so AFAIK no.

Comment: @CiroSantilliTRUMPBANISBAD Editing your answer returns "Suggested edit queue is full". ldd script you are calling in test_glibc.sh points to the host dynamic linker: "/home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc12f1b3000)". To fix this, in test_glibc.sh, change "ldd" to "${glibc_install}/bin/ldd". This will require you to add the built crt*.o files as well to the script:
-nostartfiles \
${glibc_install}/lib/crti.o \
${glibc_install}/lib/crtn.o \
${glibc_install}/lib/crt1.o \
See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634184/4726668

Comment: How does one install headers into the newly created sysroot? For example, if I install some library/headers using `apt-get` (like `ibverbs` etc.), can I get them in sysroot? I am guessing that would be tricky because my sysroot could be for a different architecture - so how does one build a program using custom glibc compiled using crosstool-ng but also specify other libraries that were previously installed on the system?

Comment: @gohar94 wouldn't more `-L`/`-I` work to add extra paths? To remove something that would be on a default path in incompatible arch, not sure. I recommend asking a new question with an example of what you want to do and linking in a new comment.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Ciro's earlier answer/solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52454710/4726668 :

@CiroSantilli Editing your answer returns "Suggested edit queue is full". The ldd script you are calling in the `test_glibc.sh` script points to the host dynamic linker: `/home/ciro/glibc/build/install/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc12f1b3000)`. To fix this, in `test_glibc.sh`, change `ldd` to `${glibc_install}/bin/ldd`. This will require you to add the built `crt`*.o files as well to the script:

```
-nostartfiles \
${glibc_install}/lib/crti.o \
${glibc_install}/lib/crtn.o \
${glibc_install}/lib/crt1.o \
```

On my GNU/Linux i386/i686 (32-bit x86 arch) machine, following is my working `test_glibc.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eux
gcc \
  -L "${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -I "${glibc_install}/include" \
  -Wl,--rpath="${glibc_install}/lib" \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker="${glibc_install}/lib/ld-linux.so.2" \
  -std=c11 \
  -nostartfiles \
  ${glibc_install}/lib/crti.o \
  ${glibc_install}/lib/crtn.o \
  ${glibc_install}/lib/crt1.o \
  -o test_glibc.out \
  -v \
  test_glibc.c \
  -pthread \
;
${glibc_install}/bin/ldd ./test_glibc.out
./test_glibc.out
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it does look interesting. When I tried it on Ubuntu 20.10 glibc 2.32 I got errors `${glibc_install}/bin/ldd ./test_glibc.out` gives `not a dynamic executable` and  `./test_glibc.out` gives `./test_glibc.out: No such file or directory`. I didn't stop to investigate further.

Comment: @Ciro At first glance, that "no such file or directory" error tells me that you probably copy-pasted the script as is, which was tested on 32-bit, and tried it on ur 64-bit arch machine. Please note that the dynamic linker is different for 32-bit vs 64-bit. That's why I had made a note there on my machine config, "GNU/Linux i386/i686 machine", which is a 32-bit arch.

Comment: Ops, yes, now I fixed that and `./test_glibc.out` worked. But the `${glibc_install}/bin/ldd ./test_glibc.out` still failed for some reason.

Comment: Maybe the "RTLDLIST" variable in that ldd script is pointing to the incorrect dynamic linker?

Answer (score 1):

Last tested on Ubuntu 20.04 with glibc development version 2.33.9000 (see `glibc/version.h`) on 27 June 2021.

### How to download and build glibc, and run its benchmarks

You can manually obtain the glibc source code here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html:

```sh
git clone https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout master
```

3rd party mirror on GitHub: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/tree/master/benchtests

See also:

1. https://kazoo.ga/a-simple-tool-to-test-malloc-performance/

### If you ever wish to manually build glibc and its benchtests, do so as follows:

```sh
# IMPORTANT: begin AT THE SAME DIRECTORY LEVEL as the `glibc` source code 
# directory, NOT inside the `glibc` source code dir! In other words, if 
# you are in the correct dir, running `ls` will show the `glibc` source
# code dir (that you just cloned) inside the dir you are in.
mkdir -p glibc-build
mkdir -p glibc-install
cd glibc-build
../glibc/configure --prefix="$(realpath "../glibc-install")"
time make -j8  # build with 8 threads (jobs); on a fast laptop this takes ~3 min.
time make install # (optional: install to the `glibc-install` dir you created)

# Build the benchtests (everything inside the `glibc/benchtests` dir) too;
# see the makefile 'glibc/benchtests/Makefile' for more build commands. 
time make bench-build -j8
# Now you have this executable file you can use for malloc speed tests, for instance!: 
#       ../glibc-build/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread

# To build **and run** all glibc benchtests, do:
time make bench
```

### References:

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html
2. https://kazoo.ga/a-simple-tool-to-test-malloc-performance/
3. https://github.com/f18m/malloc-benchmarks/blob/master/Makefile#L122-L129 : I learned much of this by studying this makefile target:

   ```
   $(glibc_install_dir)/lib/libc.so.6:
   @echo "Building GNU libc... go get a cup of coffee... this will take time!"
   mkdir -p $(glibc_build_dir)
   cd $(glibc_build_dir) && \
       ../glibc/configure --prefix=$(glibc_install_dir) && \
       make $(parallel_flags) && \
       make install
   [ -x $(glibc_build_dir)/benchtests/bench-malloc-thread ] && echo "GNU libc benchmarking utility is ready!" || echo "Cannot find GNU libc benchmarking utility! Cannot collect benchmark results"
   ```
4. [How to compile my own glibc C standard library from source and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412684/how-to-compile-my-own-glibc-c-standard-library-from-source-and-use-it/52454710#52454710)

<sub>Keywords: how to build and run glibc and its benchtests, incl. malloc benchtests, from source; build glibc from source on linux ubuntu</sub>