# while working with tensorflow model server I encounter this error: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: tensorflow, glibc

while running the [tutorial](http://cognitiveai.org/2020/09/08/using-tensorflow-ranking-bert-tfr-bert-an-end-to-end-example/), I run the code below

%%bash --bg
nohup tensorflow_model_server 
--rest_api_port=8501 
--model_name=tfrbert 
--model_base_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/app/model14/export/best_model_by_loss/" >server.log 2>&1

it worked for me befor. but now I encounter with this error:

tensorflow_model_server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by tensorflow_model_server) tensorflow_model_server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version` GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by tensorflow_model_server)
tensorflow_model_server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by tensorflow_model_server)

I searched a lot, but nothing helped. does anybody know how to solve the problem?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error means: the `tensorflow_model_server` binary you have was compiled and linked on a system with GLIBC-2.28 or newer, and you are trying to run it on a system with GLIBC-2.27 or older.

You should find a build of `tensorflow_model_server` *appropriate* for your system.

Alternatively, you could use a docker container with GLIBC-2.28 or newer, and run `tensorflow_model_server` in that container.

Another option is to build `tensorflow_model_server` yourself on your system -- the resulting binary will work on it.

Comment: thanks. but i run my codes in colab. how can i fix my problem in colab environment?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was trying to serve my trained Object Detection model on `Colab`. The reason being the GLIBC version installed on `Colab` is `2.27` whereas the latest version of Tensorflow Serving`(2.9.1)` requires the updated version of GLIBBC which happens to be `2.28`. You can read more about GLIBC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460782/what-is-glibc-what-is-it-used-for).

This is how you check the version of GLIBC : `ldd --version`

In my case, rather than using the latest version of Tensroflow Serving, I used the `1.15` version which worked very well on Google Colab. This is how I installed the `1.15` version :

```
!wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server-1.15.0/t/tensorflow-model-server/tensorflow-model-server_1.15.0_all.deb'
!dpkg -i tensorflow-model-server_1.15.0_all.deb
!pip3 install tensorflow-serving-api==1.15

!sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install this and everything will work ok .

```
!wget 'http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow-serving-apt/pool/tensorflow-model-server-universal-2.8.0/t/tensorflow-model-server-universal/tensorflow-model-server-universal_2.8.0_all.deb'
!dpkg -i tensorflow-model-server-universal_2.8.0_all.deb
```