# How does an unspecified pointer conversion behave in C++14?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, c++14, reinterpret-cast

The result of some pointer casts are described as unspecified. For example, [expr.static.cast]/13:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T,” [...] If the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A satisfies the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value represents the same address as the original pointer value, that is, A. **The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified**.

My question is: in the case where alignment is *not* satisfied, what are the possible results?

For example, are the following results permitted?

- a null pointer
- an invalid pointer value  (i.e. pointer which does not point to allocated storage of size `T`)
- a valid pointer to a `T` in a completely separate part of memory

---

Code sample for reference:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *b = (int *)"Hello, world";   // (1)

    *b = -1;                           // (2)
    std::cout << argc << '\n';
}
```

Line `(1)` triggers my above quote from [expr.static.cast]/13 because it is a `reinterpret_cast` which is covered by [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7 which defines the conversion in terms of `static_cast`ing through `void *`.

If the unspecified result may be an invalid pointer value, then line `(1)` may cause a hardware trap. (Reference: [N4430](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4430.html) which clarifies similar wording that was in C++14 and C++11).

*Corollary question:* is there any case in which line `1` would cause undefined behaviour? (I don't think so at this stage; since C++14 invalid pointer value reading is implementation-defined or causes a hardware trap).

---

Also interesting is that line `(2)` would in most cases be undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation (and perhaps other reasons too), however if the unspecified result may be `&argc` then this program could output `-1` without triggering undefined behaviour!

Comment: Err, it is unspecified.

Comment: "...then this program could output `-1` without triggering undefined behavior" is a strange -- and I would say wrong -- way to phrase it. Line (2) results in undefined behavior, always. "Undefined behavior" just means that any behavior of the program whatsoever would comply with the spec, including the behavior of outputting -1. An "unspecified value" is a value (not a behavior) that the spec does not constrain and the implementation need not document.

Comment: @Nemo how does line 2 result in UB (if `b` has the value `&argc`)

Comment: @EJP that's underspecified :P  for example an unspecified `int` could not contain `UINT_MAX`. So there is always a finite set of possibilities for an unspecified value. With `int` that's clear. With pointers... not so much

Comment: Could the assignment of the unspecified rhs value on line `(1)` to the lhs cause undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is: in the case where alignment is not satisfied, what are the possible results?

As far as I can tell [N4303: Pointer safety and placement new](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4303.html) partially answers this question, although somewhat indirectly. This paper refers to [CWG issue 1412: Problems in specifying pointer conversions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3539.html#1412)  which brought about the changes to *[expr.static.cast]/13* that you reference, specifically adding:

> [...]If the original pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A satisfies the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value represents the same address as the original pointer value, that is, A. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.[...]

In reference to this change `N4303` says (*emphasis mine*):

> Prior to the adoption of the resolution for DR 1412 [CWG1412], the value of bp is unspecified at the point of its initialization and its subsequent passing to operator new via the new-expression. **Said pointer may be null, insufficiently aligned or otherwise dangerous to use.**

So an unspecified conversion can results in:

- A null pointer
- An insufficiently aligned pointer
- A pointer that is dangerous to use

Comment: "a pointer that is dangerous to use" seems weasely. "invalid pointer value" is certainly a pointer that is dangerous to use; what other possibilities are there?

Comment: "An insufficiently aligned pointer" - as far as I can see there is no other text, besides the strict aliasing rule, that would prevent such a pointer being used. Only this clause we are discussing to potentially prevent such a pointer being created in the first place.  So , presumably, on machines that enforce hardware alignment they could not return an insufficiently aligned pointer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Just to name a few other possibilities: a pointer that doesn't compare equal to itself, or a pointer for which pointer arithmetic breaks (i.e. p+1-1 != p)

Comment: @MSalters That could only happen if `p+1` causes undefined behaviour (which does seem to be one of the cases)

Comment: @MattMcNabb you make some good comments, I don't have more to add at this point, that was all I was able to dig up.