# How do I change GCC's default search directory for crti.o?

Tags: gcc, glibc, search-path

I'd like to specify GCC's search directory for the `startfile` and
`endfile`: `crt1.o`, `crti.o` and `crtn.o`. Passing `-B` on the command line to
the GCC driver works, but is inconvenient. How do I modify the specs
file (`lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/specs`) to specify the search path for `startfile`?

I tried adding the `-B` option to the `startfile` spec and got the error:
`ld: unrecognized option '-B/gsc/btl/linuxbrew/lib'`

I then tried adding the `-B` option to the `cc1` spec and got the error:
`cc1: error: command line option '-B/gsc/btl/linuxbrew/lib' is valid
for the driver but not for C`

If it's not possible to do this via the `specs` file, is there an environment variable or a configure option to GCC that accomplishes the same goal?

I've installed a recent version of `glibc` in my home directory. Everything's working great. I've modified the `specs` file to link against the new version of `glibc`, but it's still linking against the old system version in `/usr` of `startfile` and `endfile`.

Here's a [the unanswered question](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-02/msg00016.html) on the `gcc-help` mailing list. Here's a related Linuxbrew bug, [gfortran is broken with stand alone Linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/issues/135), and a proposed fix, [gcc, binutils: link to Cellar instead of system libs](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/pull/200).

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an absolute path in the `*startfile:` and `*endfile:` sections in the specs file, instead of the default relative paths.  This will override GCC's choice of the default location.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/LibraryPathOverview, gcc will look for startup files such as `crt1.o` in `$(sysroot)/lib`, so you can specify the `--sysroot` option when running gcc, or compile gcc with `--with-sysroot`.

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried `--sysroot` with a custom built glibc it failed with another error: `cannot find libgcc_s.so.1` and it still seemed to use the host ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412684/how-to-compile-my-own-glibc-c-standard-library-from-source-and-use-it/52454710#52454710