# setting gdb breakpoint inside shared object file

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints, shared-libraries

I have an executable that dynamically loads a shared object library, let say foo.so. I do not build foo.so and it is given to me as a library to use in my code. foo.cpp compiles to give foo.so. I do not have access to foo.cpp but have foo.so. I want to set a breakpoint when my executable calls a function inside this shared library foo.so (that is when function inside foo.cpp is called). Is their a way in gdb to do so? 
I have tried

```
gdb funcname
```

but it does not seem to work. Any pointers how to break gdb at that point?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the operating system and version of gdb you are using?

Comment: I am using CentOS 5.5 and gdb 7.2.

Comment: @DeeptiJain Was the shared object library compiled with the appropriate debug flags?

Comment: @Michael GDB does *not* need the library to be compiled with debug flags to set breakpoints in it.

Comment: @EmployedRussian It's my [understanding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/322015/849425) that without the symbol table (no debug flags) that you can only do ASM level debugging.

Comment: @Michael Your understanding is *incorrect* for all UNIX machines I know of. Debug flags *do not affect* symbol table (except on ancient UNIX systems that still use `COFF`) to begin with. And when you are doing ASM level debugging, it still helps a lot to know what function you are in, and *that* does not require debug info; just the symbol table.

Answer (score 3):

> Is their a way in gdb to do so?

Yes.

> I have tried `gdb funcname`

That wouldn't work. You need to run `gdb exename`, then `break funcname` at the `(gdb)` prompt.

At that point, GDB will likely inform you that `funcname` does not yet exist (since you haven't yet dynamically loaded `foo.so`), and will ask you whether you want to create a *deferred* breakpoint. You should answer `yes`, and GDB will retry setting this breakpoint every time a new shared library is loaded. Eventually this will succeed, and you should get the breakpoint set (automatically and silently), and when you call the `funcname` later, that breakpoint will fire and GDB will stop (which is exactly what you want).